# Heroku confirmation token - Devise error (even with Sendgrid)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, devise, devise-confirmable

I am using Heroku, Devise & Sendgrid.

These are my settings in `environment/production.rb`:

```
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'myapp.herokuapp.com' }

  # ActionMailer Config
  # Setup for production - deliveries, no errors raised
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false
  config.action_mailer.default :charset => "utf-8"

  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address: "smtp.sendgrid.net",
    port: 25,
    domain: "myapp.herokuapp.com",
    authentication: "plain",
    user_name: ENV["SENDGRID_USERNAME"],
    password: ENV["SENDGRID_PASSWORD"]
  }
```

I have set the `ENV` variables on Heroku fine, and when I register an account it sends the email correctly to the right email address.

It is just when I click the confirmation link, I get a bunch of errors and it doesn't confirm the account:

```
Started GET "/users/confirmation?confirmation_token=dZf6Jqc7x88q8tyH5bZp" for XX.XX.XX.XX at 2013-05-20 20:59:29 +0000
2013-05-20T20:59:29.413847+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-05-20T20:59:29.413847+00:00 app[web.1]: NameError (uninitialized constant Confirmation):
2013-05-20T20:59:29.413847+00:00 app[web.1]:
```

**Edit 1**

This is my `User.rb` the Devise portion:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  rolify
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
  # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :confirmable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :role_ids, :as => :admin
  attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me
```

**Edit 2**

This is what happens in my `development.log` when I do the same thing.

```
Started GET "/users/confirmation?confirmation_token=Gs3UYE2m6D84zfuXfa66" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-05-20 17:12:39 -0500
Processing by ConfirmationsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"confirmation_token"=>"Gs3UYE2m6D84zfuXfa66"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 10ms

NameError - uninitialized constant Confirmation:
  (gem) activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:520:in `load_missing_constant'
```

I have run all the migrations, maybe I need to generate a new migration for the `Confirmable` module? How do I do that?

**Edit 3**

This is what my `users` table within my `schema.rb` looks like:

```
  create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  :default => "", :null => false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     :default => "", :null => false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          :default => 0
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at",                             :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                             :null => false
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "confirmation_token"
    t.datetime "confirmed_at"
    t.datetime "confirmation_sent_at"
    t.string   "unconfirmed_email"
    t.float    "sales_today"
    t.float    "sales_this_week"
    t.float    "sales_lifetime"
    t.boolean  "is_seller"
  end
```

So it seems to me that the `Confirmable` module is all setup.

**Edit 4**

I forgot that I actually do override the `ConfirmationsController`:

```
class ConfirmationsController < Devise::ConfirmationsController
  load_and_authorize_resource

  protected
    def after_confirmation_path_for(resource_name, resource)
      if resource.has_role? :seller
        new_item_path
      else
        root_path
      end
    end
end
```

Comment: This isn't actually a SendGrid issue at all, this is a devise issue.  Mind sharing your code for your devise user?

Comment: I assume you mean the Devise configs for the User model, right? If so...I have done that. If you want something else, let me know. Thanks!

Comment: Have you overridden any of the default Devise classes?  And does this work if you confirm in development mode rather than production?

Comment: I maybe wrong but doest environment/production.rb gets replaced by Heroku?

Comment: That's a fair point, shouldn't matter, the issue is in the model.

Comment: You guys seem to be right. I just tested it in development mode and I am getting a similar error. Lemme update the question with the log output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like when you added your `:confirmable` model you forgot to migrate the database. I can tell by these lines

```
Started GET "/users/confirmation?confirmation_token=dZf6Jqc7x88q8tyH5bZp" for XX.XX.XX.XX at 2013-05-20 20:59:29 +0000
2013-05-20T20:59:29.413847+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-05-20T20:59:29.413847+00:00 app[web.1]: NameError (uninitialized constant Confirmation):
```

mainly

```
NameError (uninitialized constant Confirmation):
```

The error is somewhere in your app. I'm guessing in the database, because devise probably won't even set up the model without the DB table.

You overrode the ConfirmationsController. Do not forget to call `super` on every method you override.

Also: just because your schema.rb says a column exists, it doesn't mean it actually does. MAKE SURE TO CHECK YOUR MIGRATION IN TO VERSION CONTROL, OTHERWISE IT WILL NEVER REACH THE SERVER.

Now: Go into your terminal and run `heroku run rails console`. Try out some code in there, and post any error logs you get. this is a very powerful tool.

Best,

Brian

Comment: You may be right. I updated the question with logs from my `development.log`. So now, the question is...how do I fix this? I have run `rake db:migrate` recently....so that's not the issue.

Comment: Also, in my `users` table in my `Schema.rb`, I have these columns:     `t.string   "confirmation_token"`, `t.datetime "confirmed_at"`, `t.datetime "confirmation_sent_at"`. So what else is missing?

Comment: I forgot that I had tried to override the ConfirmationsController - so that may be what is giving me this headache now?